# creating a new column on if condition from different columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataset. I need `Col A * B * C * D * E` in a new column `Score` based on the conditions:

Where if `ID` & `VID` is same, but `QID` is unique or different, choose the higher value from `Col E` in calculation of the new column `Score`

```
ID     VID     QID     A     B     C     D     E
121    212     123     1     2     1     1     1
121    212     435     1     2     1     1     5
223    244     567     2     3     5     1     2
313    232     709     5     1     2     1     3
313    232     887     5     1     2     1     2
454    969     457     1     3     2     2     4
454    969     457     1     2     1     2     4
```

Expected outcome is something like :

```
ID     VID     QID     A     B     C     D     E     Score
121    212     123     1     2     1     1     1     10 (because based on ID and VID I want to choose higher value in column E while calculating, and apply the same to those rows)
121    212     435     1     2     1     1     5     10
223    244     567     2     3     5     1     2     60
313    232     709     5     1     2     1     3     30
313    232     887     5     1     2     1     2     30
454    969     457     1     3     2     2     4     48
454    969     457     1     2     1     2     4     16
```

I have tried `.sort` in order to bring `Col E` in a descending or ascending format and then calculating but couldn't write the logic behind the calculation. Just a beginner trying to work this problem for few days now.

Comment: please add your expected output and any attempts to solve the problem (in pseudo or real code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be over-complicating the solution by a bit but this is how a quick solution would look like to me: 
Part 1: Calculate Unique Count of QID and Max of E

```
df_tempA = df.groupby(["ID", "VID"]).agg({
    'QID':"nunique",
    'E': "max"
}).reset_index().rename(columns={'QID':"QIDCount",'E':"MaxE"})

print(df_tempA)   
    ID  VID  QIDCount  MaxE
0  121  212         2     5
1  223  244         1     2
2  313  232         2     3
3  454  969         1     4
```

Part 2: Join with the original dataframe

```
df_result = pd.merge(df, df_tempA, on=["ID", "VID"])

print(df_result)
    ID  VID  QID  A  B  C  D  E  QIDCount  MaxE
0  121  212  123  1  2  1  1  1         2     5
1  121  212  435  1  2  1  1  5         2     5
2  223  244  567  2  3  5  1  2         1     2
3  313  232  709  5  1  2  1  3         2     3
4  313  232  887  5  1  2  1  2         2     3
5  454  969  457  1  3  2  2  4         1     4
6  454  969  457  1  2  1  2  4         1     4
```

Part 3: Create Score column based on conditions

```
df_result['Score'] = df_result.apply(lambda df: df['A']*df['B']*df['C']*df['D']*df['E'] 
                                    if df['QIDCount'] ==1 
                                    else df['A']*df['B']*df['C']*df['D']*df['MaxE'], 
                                    axis=1)

print(df_result)
    ID  VID  QID  A  B  C  D  E  QIDCount  MaxE  Score
0  121  212  123  1  2  1  1  1         2     5     10
1  121  212  435  1  2  1  1  5         2     5     10
2  223  244  567  2  3  5  1  2         1     2     60
3  313  232  709  5  1  2  1  3         2     3     30
4  313  232  887  5  1  2  1  2         2     3     30
5  454  969  457  1  3  2  2  4         1     4     48
6  454  969  457  1  2  1  2  4         1     4     16
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for this revert, it is working fine so far. Just a little more help please, I would like to divide the `Score` by 100. How do I achieve that?

Comment: @ashnaa1610 - Use `df['Score'] = (df.assign(E = df.groupby(['ID','VID'])['E'].transform('max')).iloc[:, 3:].prod(axis=1).div(100))`

Comment: @ashnaa1610 You can use the above comment or for simplicity just use `df_result['Score'] = df_result['Score']/100` at the end.  Also, please go through this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html). It will help you get started with pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) for overwite column `E` by max values per groups and then multiple by [`DataFrame.prod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.prod.html) all columns with omit first 3 selected [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df['Score'] = (df.assign(E = df.groupby(['ID','VID'])['E'].transform('max'))
                 .iloc[:, 3:]
                 .prod(axis=1))
print (df)
    ID  VID  QID  A  B  C  D  E  Score
0  121  212  123  1  2  1  1  1     10
1  121  212  435  1  2  1  1  5     10
2  223  244  567  2  3  5  1  2     60
3  313  232  709  5  1  2  1  3     30
4  313  232  887  5  1  2  1  2     30
5  454  969  457  1  3  2  2  4     48
6  454  969  457  1  2  1  2  4     16
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.groupby(['ID','VID'])['E'].transform('max'))
0    5
1    5
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    4
6    4
Name: E, dtype: int64
```